# "Member access into incomplete type" error, C++ Xcode SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, member

[image]I am getting the error "Member access into incomplete type" and I'm not sure why. I am trying to get the player to jump and land on the ground and then walk on the ground but as of right now I couldn't cause I had the player moving down with the following code

```
                    case SDLK_SPACE:
                        transform->velocity.y = 3;
                        sprite->Play("Walk Side");
                    break;
```

But what I want is velocity.y = 0 when it detects a collision so he can walk where that is.

Component.h

```
#ifndef Components_h
#define Components_h
#include "ECS.hpp"
#include "TransformComponent.h"
#include "SpriteComponent.h"
#include "ColliderComponent.h"
#include "KeyboardController.h"
#include "TileComponent.h"


#endif /* Components_h */
```

ColliderComponent.h

```
#ifndef ColliderComponent_h
#define ColliderComponent_h

#include <string>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "Components.h"
#include "TextureManager.hpp"

class ColliderComponent : public Component
{
public:
    SDL_Rect collider;
    std::string tag;

    SDL_Texture* tex;
    SDL_Rect srcR, destR;

    TransformComponent* transform;

    ColliderComponent(std::string t)
    {
        tag = t;
    }

    ColliderComponent(std::string t, int xpos, int ypos, int size)
    {
        tag = t;
        collider.x = xpos;
        collider.y = ypos;
        collider.h = collider.w = size;
    }

    void init() override
    {
        if(!entity->hasComponent<TransformComponent>())
        {
            entity->addComponent<TransformComponent>();
        }
        transform = &entity->getComponent<TransformComponent>();

        tex = TextureManager::LoadTexture("/Users/Shared/Relocated Items/Security/2D game engine/2D game engine - Textures/assets/PlatformWorldTest_ColliderTileSet.png");
        srcR = { 0, 0, 32, 32 };
        destR = { collider.x, collider.y, collider.w, collider.h };
    }

    void update() override
    {
        if(tag != "terrain")
        {
            collider.x = static_cast<int>(transform->position.x);
            collider.y = static_cast<int>(transform->position.y);
            collider.w = transform->width * transform->scale;
            collider.h = transform->height * transform->scale;
        }

        destR.x = collider.x - Game::camera.x;
        destR.y = collider.y - Game::camera.y;
    }

    void draw() override
    {
        TextureManager::Draw(tex, srcR, destR, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
    }

};

#endif /* ColliderComponent_h */
```

KeyboardComponent.h

```
#ifndef KeyboardController_h
#define KeyboardController_h

#include "Game.hpp"
#include "ECS.hpp"
#include "Components.h"

class KeyboardController : public Component
{
public:
    TransformComponent *transform;
    SpriteComponent *sprite;
    ColliderComponent *collision;

    void init() override
    {
        transform = &entity->getComponent<TransformComponent>();
        sprite = &entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>();
        collision = &entity->getComponent<ColliderComponent>();
    }

    void update() override
    {
        if(Game::event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch (Game::event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
                /*case SDLK_w:
                    transform->velocity.y = -1;
                    sprite->Play("Walk Back");
                    break;*/
                case SDLK_a:
                    transform->velocity.x = -1;
                    sprite->Play("Walk Side");
                    sprite->spriteflip = SDL_FLIP_HORIZONTAL;
                    break;
                case SDLK_d:
                    transform->velocity.x = 1;
                    sprite->Play("Walk Side");
                    break;
                /*case SDLK_s:
                    transform->velocity.y = 1;
                    sprite->Play("Walk Forward");
                    break;*/
                case SDLK_SPACE:
                    transform->velocity.y = -3;
                    sprite->Play("Walk Side");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        if(Game::event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
        {
            switch (Game::event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
                /*case SDLK_w:
                    transform->velocity.y = 0;
                    sprite->Play("Idle");
                    break;*/
                case SDLK_a:
                    transform->velocity.x = 0;
                    sprite->Play("Idle");
                    sprite->spriteflip = SDL_FLIP_NONE;
                    break;
                case SDLK_d:
                    transform->velocity.x = 0;
                    sprite->Play("Idle");
                    break;
                /*case SDLK_s:
                    transform->velocity.y = 0;
                    sprite->Play("Idle");
                    break;*/
                case SDLK_SPACE:
                   #ifndef ColliderComponent_h
                   #error Not seen
                   #endif
                    if(collision->tag != "terrain") //ERROR IS HERE WITH POINTER ->, "Member access into incomplete type 'ColliderComponent'"
                    {
                        transform->velocity.y = 3;
                        sprite->Play("Walk Side");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    transform->velocity.y = 0;
                    sprite->Play("Walk Side");
                    }
                    break;
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    Game::isRunning = false;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
};
#endif /* KeyboardController_h */
```

Comment: How do you expect the definition of `ColliderComponent` to become visible at the place of the error? Whatever your answer is, please prove by inserting a `#ifndef ColliderComponent_h \n #error Not seen. \n #endif` just before the error line.

Comment: Im not sure I follow?

Comment: Your problem is an access via pointer to an unknown class. The definition/declaration of that class must be seen. It is in the other header. I do not see where it gets inlcuded. Please explain how the includes are supposed to make it visible. If you cannot, then that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for editing my proposed line into the shown code. That does however not help. You need to try copmpiling and report the result. I expect an error message.

Comment: And that does of course only work if your replace the literal `\n` by newlines in your code. I.e. those are three lines, not one.

Comment: isn't the class Im pointing to `ColliderComponent ` I created a member 'collision' like I did with 'transform' and 'sprite' and then I initialized is in 'void init() override' and 'getComponent' The '#include "Component.h" '  includes 'ColliderComponent.h'

Comment: I added the 'Component.h' header

Comment: And it includes the error line before the dependency. That is your problem. What happens if you include the other way around? Hopefully you do not have a circular dependency.

Comment: what do you mean? the error line is before which dependency?

Comment: I tried added the code you said and compiling but I'm not sure I put it right. nothing is happening. I fixed in the example. did you mean like that?

Comment: The error line is the line which causes the error `if(collision->tag != "terrain")`. The dependency is the class definition needed in that line `class ColliderComponent {...}`.

Comment: I.e. swap `#include "ColliderComponent.h"` and `#include "KeyboardController.h"`. So that when the error line is compiled the dependency has already been seen.

Comment: And remove the `#ifndef` line I proposed, you misunderstood that debugging technique anyway.

Comment: I tried swapping them in 'Component.h' but nothing changed

Comment: Do not edit the shown code with each proposed experiment. Especially not with the solution.

Comment: OK, enough guessing. Make a [mre]. Please spend extra effort on the "minimal". I.e. throw away anything which is not needed to reproduce the described error message.

Comment: Pictures of text are little help. Make a MRE please.

Comment: I don't know how to make a minimal reproducible example. I took a screenshot of what the error is showing. I am changing to code so you can see what I am doing if its what you wanted or not.

Comment: Screenshot is of little help. Read the link. Work, show. Sorry, but this is the way to debug strange errors.

Comment: Showing how you applied my proposals is of course not a bad idea. But you should not change your question by doing so. Consider writing at the end of the question something like "I tried a proposed experiment by changing like this: ...".

Comment: I like the answer by BSO. However, in order to understand your problem, you should continue trying to make a MRE.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define the functions `KeyboardController::init()` and `KeyboardController:: update()` directly into the .h but do it in the `.cpp` of the class then in this cpp file add `#include "ColliderComponent.h"` and your problems will be gone.

Normally on a good projects your need to have zero `#include` in your `.h` file, only forward declaration, this is way better for compilation time.

Comment: This does not trace the mechanism of the problem, but provides a paushal solution. Which however is suitable (in the absence of templates etc.). Decent.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your includes. Since `ColliderComponent.h` includes `Components.h`, it will start including all the files in `Components.h` recursively. So when `Components.h` is included, it tries to include `ColliderComponent.h` again, but due to include guards it will ignore its contents, and move on to include `KeyboardComponent.h`. At this point, `ColliderComponent` is **not** fully defined. In fact, it's not actually defined at all from what code you've shown, so I assume there's a forward declaration of it somewhere. Your `#ifndef … #error` doesn't throw a compilation error because at that point, `ColliderComponent.h` was already (partially) included, so `ColliderComponent_h` is already defined.

The best solution, is probably just to move the function definitions into a separate source file, which includes the `CompilerComponent.h` header. Also, try to remove unneeded `#include`s from your headers, and stick with forward declarations.

Comment: That is what I was thinking of. Just a little bit too much guessing without feedback from OP. Still nice.